# rxjs to launch upload one by one in Angular app

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have created dragdrop component to upload file, user can uploads 5 files in same times but even if i display all images in the preview i want to launch upload one by one after have received server's response for the previous file

What is the better way to do that with rxjs and angular(v4)

this is my code:

```
public onFileSelected(event) {
    if (event && event.type == 'uploadImageProject') {

        const previews$ = Observable.from(event.files)
            .filter(file => file instanceof File)
            .map(file => file)
            .take(5)

        const previewSub = previews$.subscribe(file => {
            this.previews = [];
            this.addPreview(file as File);
        });

        this._storeSubscription.push(previewSub);

    }
}

private addPreview(file: File): void {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (event) => {
        this.uploadFile(event.currentTarget['result']);
        this.previews.push(event.currentTarget['result']);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

private uploadFile(imgBase64): void {
    const uploadId = UUID.UUID();        
    const fileToUpload = {projectId: this.projectId, upload: {file: imgBase64, id: uploadId, type:'picture', order: 0}};
    this._store.dispatch(addPictureOnProject(fileToUpload));
}
```

For now the script works but uploads start together, function addPreview display picture on my app and uploadFile dispatch an action(redux) to call the service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of random ideas:

You could get real rxjs-y and use [concatAll](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/concatall.html), where your observables are your http requests. Based on the docs it says concatAll waits for each inner observable to finish before starting the next one.

```
of(files.map(file => this.fileUploadService.upload(file))
  .pipe(concatAll())
  .subscribe(res => {
      /* do whatever */
  });
```

Or you could just do something like this:

```
async function doUploadsSequentially(files: File[]): Promise<void> {
   files.map(async function(file: File) {
      const res = await this.uploadService.upload(file).pipe(toPromise()); 
   }
}
```

Of course, you'll need to work in some error handling and whatever other logic you need to do after each one uploads. I didn't test this, and I'm not an rxjs wizard so some tweaking may be necessary.

Comment: thank you for your help, concatAll is what i was looking for. i will add the code later if it can help other. need to refactor